# Re-run the Last AJAX Call Made

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently trying to refresh a small section of my application which is being generated by an AJAX call, I need to be able to target the last call that was made and run it again with the same parameters and run through a different button click. The way it received the data before was from the previously clicked button. I am working in MVC with C# on the back-end. Here is my AJAX call:

```
$('.eventlevel').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/GetTasksForEventLevel",
        data: {
            EventLevelID: $(this).attr('data-EventLevelID')
        },
        success: function (eventLevel) {
            $('#tasks').html('&nbsp;');
            $.each(eventLevel.data, function (key, value) {
                var html = " <div class='dashbox col-lg-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5'>";
                if (value.EventLevel == 3) {
                    html += "<div class='green-circle'></div>";
                }
                else if (value.EventLevel == 2) {
                    html += "<div class='yellow-circle'></div>";
                }
                else if (value.EventLevel == 1) {
                    html += "<div class='red-circle'></div>";
                }
                else if (value.EventLevel == 4) {
                    html += "<div class='grey-circle'></div>";
                }
                html += "<p class='bodytext'>" + value.EventDescription + "</p>";
                html += "<p class='bodytext'>Pending Items: (" + value.EventValue + ")</p>";
                html += "<p class='bodytext'>Last Updated: " + value.EventDateTimeText + "</p>";
                html += "<p><a href='#'>View History</a></p>";
                html += "<button data-MonitoringEventID='" + value.MonitoringEventID + "' class='raise'>Raise Alert</button>";
                html += "<button class='review'>Commit Review</button> </div>";
                $('#tasks').append(html);
            }); 
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Thanks in advance for all help that is offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend an ajax wrapper function that would accept the ajax object as a parameter and store that in a variable to keep track of the "last" call.  Something like this should work:

```
var lastAjaxCall;
function ajaxWrapper(obj){
    lastAjaxCall = obj;
    $.ajax(obj);
}
```

A function calling your last ajax call would be as simple as the following:

```
function executeLastAjaxCall(){
    if(lastAjaxCall) $.ajax(lastAjaxCall);
}
```

Comment: Would i be placing the function within my click? 'var lastAjaxCall;
            function ajaxWrapper(obj) {
                lastAjaxCall = obj;
                $.ajax(obj);
            }
            $('#refresh').on('click',
            function executeLastAjaxCall() {
                if (lastAjaxCall) $.ajax(lastAjaxCall);
            });'

Comment: Yes, simply replace the `$.ajax` call in your code with a call to the `ajaxWrapper`.  Then when you want to do the "execute last call" behavior, simply call `executeLastAjaxCall()` from your second button click event

Comment: Oh you meant the function declaration itself... that needs to go outside of the click function definition shown in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `ajax` call inside a function:

```
function getData(callback){
 $.ajax({
  success: callback,
  error: callback
 })
}

getData(function(data)){
 //Do something with data...
}
```